# create and set custom read only attached properties from cpp

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qtquick2

say i have some custom view class in c++ which defines a set of attached properties. A component delegate to instantiate a viewItem for when a model object is added. How would i make the Attached properties work properly, to keep external data the attache cannot set itself?

Demo code example

```
class someModel: public QObject
{
    QOBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(data_1 ...)
    Q_PROPERTY(data_2 ...)
    public:
    SomeView(QObject* parent);
};

class SomviewViewAttached: public QObject
{
    QOBJECT
    // read only  properties with signals
    Q_PROPERTY(SomeView view...)
    Q_PROPERTY(SomeModel model...)
    Q_PROPERTY(int index ...)
    public:
    SomviewViewAttached(QObject* parent);
};

class SomeView : public QQuickItem
{
    QOBJECT
    // ill skip giving the full get setter implementation
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlCommponent delegate .........)
public:
    SomeView(QObject* parent);
    Q_INVOKABLE void addToView(SomeModel* model);
private:
    List<SomeModel*> items;
static SomviewViewAttached *qmlAttachedProperties(QObject *item)
{
    return new SomeViewAttached(item);
}

};
QML_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(SomeView,QML_HAS_ATTACHED_PROPERTIES)
```

in qml the usage would be

```
SomeView{
    id: view

    Component{
        Item{
            foo1: model.data_1
            foo2: model.data_2
            number : SomeView.index
            condition : SomeView.view.something...
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: view.addToView(new someModel)
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about `qmlAttachedPropertiesObject`? What's your goal? Why do you need an attached object (`SomeView` here) in addition to a context property (`model`) ?

Comment: i am using qmlAttachedPropertiesObject just after the creation of my attache to set a linked list node the attache is bound to with a setter not visible to qml. My actual problem is far more complicated and the code is just a dummy example. A DelegaModel provide the attached properties model and itemsIndex. the itemsIndex is Managed by The DelegateModel and not the attache, but each attache access its own visual index. How is that done. because i need to do something similar